# Android - Wait for result from Location Services to continue on create()

Tags: android

I have an application that when it starts it trys to start getting the current location because that can take a while. It only needs a current location once not a listener to keep getting location info. The issue is that when location services is turned off it crashes. I added code to alert the user to turn on location service. It promps the user but then crashes when it gets to the code to get current location. I was wondering:
1) Can I get a response from the location services and use that to test then run the code to current location in the On Create for the app..
Here is my code..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //This will test to see if location services is on then prompts and
    // takes user to location services
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
            !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        // Build the alert dialog
        android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
        builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });
        Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    //This is the code that calls the get best location
    //It crashes now when location services is off
    //I would like to say pause till that above activity is done
    //test if the user turned it on... then run
    MyLocation my_location = new MyLocation();
    my_location.init(MainActivity.this, locationResult);
```